# Booking system for timeslots

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create an online booking system with PHP and MYSQL, but I keep getting stuck when it comes to creating the database tables structure.

This is the table structure I have so far: (pseudo)

```
TABLE: 'times'

time_id | int | AI
time | datetime? (is this the best approch, if so how would the PHP code look for the datetime format?)
available | boolean


TABLE: 'bookings'

booking_id | int | AI
client_id | int | foreign key
manager_id | int | foreign key
time_id | int | foreign key
```

Within the system, I want to be able to:

- Create a new date within the admin panel, and then the users of the system can create a booking time slot if it is available.

Times can only be one of the following choices: (this is where i'm confused on if I should store one of the times below as a DATETIME, or Unix Timestamp etc...)

3:05
3:10
3:15
3:20
3:25
3:30
3:35
3:40
3:45
3:50
3:55
4:00
4:05
4:10
4:15
4:20
4:25
4:30
4:35
4:40
4:45
4:50
4:55
5:00
5:05
5:10
5:15
5:20
5:25
5:30
5:35
5:40
5:45
5:50
5:55
6:00

Can somebody assist me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for future, format your table columns using a pipe, rather than -. Makes it easier to read .

Comment: You talk in answer about TIME and then you define a datetime. In MySQL [time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) exists. Does booking table should be a foreign key to times table? If yes, is times and booking a 1:1 relation ship? And is available a computed field?

Comment: @danihp : I have just revised my question, could you take a look at it please mate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--Edit--
Based on your latest edit, it appears you want to display a select list of pre-set times, then insert a selected time into the database. If this is correct then timestamp won't help you, as a timestamp is a specific instance of time from January 1, 1970 until January 19, 2038.

For your example, we can hardcode timeslots, consider the following:

```
class Time
{
    const TIMESLOT_MIN = 3;
    const TIMESLOT_MAX = 6;

    public static function getTimeslots()
    {
        $timeslots = array();

        for ($i = self::TIMESLOT_MIN ; $i <= self::TIMESLOT_MAX ; $i++) {

            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 60 ; $j +=5) {

                if ($j < 10) {
                    $j = '0'. $j;
                }

                $timeslots[] = $i . ':' . $j;
            }
        }

        return $timeslots;
    }
}

var_dump(Time::getTimeslots());
```

--Original--
Storing in UNIX timestamp using either time() from PHP or now() from MySQL will ensure a consistent date/time storage format. This way your application can safely assume that any references to the date column in question is a timestamp and format accordingly for meaningful a view.

Another consideration is to ensure all your timestamps are stored in UTC (universal time code), so that you don't have to convert timestamps going into the database, only coming out of the database. Baselining your system, both at the OS level and Database level will make your life easier down the road, with respect to timezone conversions.

You may also want to look into [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html), it will allow you set one column per table to current timestamp, something like:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I have just revised my question, could you take a look at it please mate?

Comment: @JoelMurphy: Updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I myself prefer unix timestamp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time, that way I just store as an integer anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew . I'll look into the unix timestamp datatype now.

Comment: I have just revised my question, could you take a look at it please mate?